# Northgard Achievements in Custom maps

Tags: achievements, northgard

In Northgard you are able to create custom maps, are they valid for getting achievements?

The reason why i am asking is because certain achievements require a kill x amount of these monsters but due to the randomized map layout and content it becomes a lot of retries :| which take a while due to the fog of war effect not revealing what is on the map and what not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, otherwise game's Steam Workshop would be full of "Achivement hunt" mods.